# How to get the first page of a pdf without load the entire file to the memory using Java/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, pdf, file-upload

I created a rest API to upload PDF files using Spring Boot and Apache file upload streaming API. The main idea is not to consume a lot of memory or use the disk when a user sends large files.

My controller looks like this:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    public String uploadAsStream(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, FileUploadException {

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

        FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            
            FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            ItemInputStream stream = (ItemInputStream) item.openStream();

            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                //saves the inputstream into S3 storage
                return objectStorage.putObject(stream); 
            }
             
        }
        
        throw new FileUploadException("No file uploaded.");
    }
```

Now I need to read only the first page of the pdf to generate a thumbnail image. How to do this without load the entire file into the memory?

Comment: are u using any third party Jar like PDF box ?

Comment: Considering your comment to Franco's answer, *"I need to read the pieces corresponding to the first page of the pdf"*, you appear to have some misconception concerning the PDF file format: The internal PDF objects required for drawing a single page might be spread over the whole file.

Comment: You'll in particular need the last pieces (as that's where the pointer to the cross reference information is), then the pieces containing the cross reference information (in simple cases also the last ones, but they may also be in several linked pieces spread over the whole file). Using the cross references you can then retrieve the catalog, from there the page tree, from there the first page, and from there (recursively) the content streams, resources, annotations, etc. used for rendering that page. All these objects may again be spread all over the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's too ambiguos the question without telling us what you need to do.

You can use PDFBox to read the file, and extract the text if you need to work with it, or read it with buffered to anything else.

Take a look: https://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: In the example above, pdf will be sent in parts. So, I need to read the pieces corresponding to the first page of the pdf that was sent to generate a thumbnail image, but in my researches, all approaches that I found loading the entire file to memory and then taken the first page. I'm going to take a look at the pdfbox. Thanks!!!

Comment: What makes you think that things are serialized in a PDF? PDFs can contain objects on the first page in any order in the stream. You cannot figure out what the first page is without reading the whole thing.